# preg_match( ) for @school.edu mail Register-Login

Tags: php

Please help me to implement Edu mail in Register Page (must be PHP)

```
if(preg_match('/^\w+@school\.edu$/i', $source_string))
    valid Email
    header(home.html)
else
    header(register.html)
    //error message
```

Comment: So what's wrong (without obvious syntax errors in your code)?

Comment: There are missing braces in your code but the regular expression works well it seems to me not...?

Comment: That does not look like valid PHP code. Also, if you just want to check whether `$source_string` ends with `@school.edu`, there are better ways to check that (namely `str_ends_with()`)